# Expression has changed

Tags: angular, angularfire2, reactivex

There are myriad questions related to this particular error, but the error itself is related to change detection and unidirectional flow and can be caused by myriad problems. The questions I've read and the resources regarding the above-mentioned concepts haven't helped me to solve my particular issue as of yet.

(I'm using Firebase as my database with Angularfire2.) Here's the code...

**member-profile.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'member-profile',
  templateUrl: './member-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./member-profile.component.css']
})

export class MemberProfileComponent implements OnInit {
...     
  ngOnInit() {
    this.member = this.memberViewService.getMember(this.uid)
  }
}
```

**member-profile.component.html: (problematic line)**

```
<div *ngIf="(member | async)?.tierThreeCount > 0" class="badge">
```

**member-view.component.html:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li [class.active]="router.url == '/member-view/member-profile/' + uid"><a routerLink="/member-view/member-profile/{{uid}}">Profile</a></li>
    <li *ngIf="(user | async)?.uid === uid" [class.active]="router.url == '/member-view/member-settings'"><a routerLink="/member-view/member-settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**member-view.service.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MemberViewService {
  getMember(uid: string): Observable<any> {
    let results = this.db.object(`members/${uid}`)
    return results
  }
}
```

The `member-profile` component template is displayed in the `member-view` component after `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. (Does this make the former a child of the latter?) In any case, there doesn't appear to be any data flow from `member-profile` to `member-view`. `member-profile` gets its data from the `member-view` service with `getMember()`.

But `<div *ngIf="(member | async)?.tierThreeCount > 0" class="badge">` causes the error:

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Object]'. Current value: 'false'.
```

It seems to have something to do with the logic because the actual binding `{{(member | async )?.tierThreeCount}}` within the `ngIf` `<div>` does not trigger the error when `ngIf` is removed.

**Update:**

Moving the `ngIf` check whether the node exists in the template to the `ngOnInit` life cycle hook resolves this. The way to do this is to assign a value to a property `doesNodeExist` in the life cycle hook. Then in the template you'd check whether the property `doesNodeExist` exists with `*ngIf=doesNodeExist`. This solution isn't ideal, however, because the template contains multiple of these checks. I'd rather not create a property for each check. I'd like to understand what is causing this, instead.

Comment: Can you humour me and try the following? In your component class: `this.doesTierThreeExist = this.memberViewService.getMember(this.uid).pipe(map(memeber => memeber.tierThreeCount > 0));` and in your template `<div *ngIf="doesTierThreeExist | async" class="badge">`

Comment: `Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.` I assume pipe is new to RxJS? I'm a few versions behind on RxJS. I just picked up this project again after being away for almost a year. Is there an alternative you have in mind for pipe? If not, I can just update. I might break more stuff doing that, of course...

Comment: Ah yeah it was added in v5. If you are pre v5 you should be able to do `this.memberViewService.getMember(this.uid).map(memeber => memeber.tierThreeCount > 0)` (without the pipe). You will need to import `map` though. I don't remember the import path off by hard.

Comment: That actually didn't work. How about this: `this.memberViewService.getMember(this.uid).subscribe(data => {
  if(data.tierThreeCount > 0) {
   this.doesTierThreeExist = data
  }
 })`

Comment: Sure give it a try. If that works what I don't like about that solution is that now you need to manually handle the subscription in your component. i.e. make sure you unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought I'd use it for diagnosis. Anyway, it doesn't work. :D Error thrown on line with `*ngIf="doesTierThreeExist | async"`. I see what you're going for here. These errors are being thrown even when the node exists, though.

Comment: Hold on, get rid of the `async` pipe if you are setting the `doesTierThreeExist` property within `.subscribe` in your component class.

Comment: Of course! This seems to work, but the issue is that there are many of these checks--tier 3, tier 2, tier 1, voteCount, etc. I'd rather understand what's happening than to create a property for each of these.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately I don't know the exact reason.

Comment: Well, so what are we achieving with this? We’re moving the logic that checks whether the node exists from the ngIf in the template into the ngOnInit lifecycle hook. Any clues to be gleaned from this?